# C++ version of system header files cannot be found

Tags: c++, c, sqlite, gcc, qmake

with "... after adding **sqlite.c** in project" I should continue, because every thing was fine. Headers like `cassert`, `cerrno`, `cstdio`, let say, `c*` do exist and normally compiler do see them and compile.

After adding `sqlite3.c` into the project, now I imagine that `.h` version of those header files (`assert.h`, `errno.h`, etc.) are being added into compilaton first, which then prevents including `c*` header files in other files.

The compiler reports this: `"cassert: No such file or directory"`, which is not the truth.

I am compiling with `qmake`/`gcc`.

How could I fix this?

**Edit:** It seems that the problem is related with precompiled header. After @Caduchon's comment, I have looked again compilation log, then I saw this for precompiled header:

```
gcc -x c++-header pre.hpp
```

...

```
gcc -x c-header pre.hpp
```

Precompiled header is added into compilation 2 times. The second one is as `c-header`. I imagine that when there was no `.c` file in project, precompiled header was being processed only 1 time as `c++-header`. But when there is also a `.c` file, it is being compiled also as `c-header`.

Comment: Files that include `cassert` etc. should be compiled as C++. Are you compiling them as C instead? If the project contains C++ and C files, you should compile each one in the correct language.

Comment: I compile with C++, as always. I have only added sqlite3.c. I did not change compiler.

Comment: Many compilers will automatically compile `.c` files as C. Try renaming the file, see if the problem goes away.

Comment: Actually, I have tried with setting QMAKE_CC as C++ compiler to be sure, with no difference.

Comment: That your file is somehow being compiled as C (or at least with an include path appropriate for C) is the only explanation that makes sense. The idea that `<assert.h>` somehow prevents `<cassert>` being included does not make sense.

Comment: Also, all these c* files are in a precompiled header. Not sure if this also affects the problem. But every thing happened after adding a .c file.

Comment: Can you show the compilation line from the log ?

Comment: #ifdef __cplusplus should make the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was because of precompiled header. When a `.c` file is introduced into project, then precompiled header was being compiled also as `c-header` file. Commenting out `C++` part of the header for C-compiler resolved the problem:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
#endif
```